# Convert array of objects with paths strings into nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, tree, hierarchy

I have to convert an array of objects containing paths into a hierarchy tree list. The paths looks like this: `"1/3/2"`, where 1 is the parent of 3, 3 is the parent of 2 and so on. The depth of the hierarchy and number of children is unlimited, meaning it could look like this: `"1/3/2/2/33/33/444/1"` or this: `"2/"`.

The array I have right now looks likes this:

```
[
      {
          id: 1,
          path: "1",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        path: "1/1/1",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        path: "1/1",
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        path: "1/1/2",
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        path: "2/1",
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        path: "2/2",
      },
      {
        id: 7,
          path: "2/",
      }
  ]
```

And I need it to look like this:

```
[
        {
          id: 1,
          path: "1/",
          children: [
            {
              id: 3,
              path: "1/1",
              children: [
                {
                  id: 2,
                  path: "1/1/1",
                },
                {
                  id: 4,
                  path: "1/1/2",
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 7,
          path: "2/",
          children: [
            {
              id: 5,
              path: "2/1",
            },
            {
              id: 6,
              path: "2/2",
            },
          ]
        }
      ]
```

I am trying hard to come up with a good solution to solve this but I could really need som help

Comment: Share any attempt?

Comment: Part of the problem is that your path structure is inconsistent. It would be less confusing to solve this if the path of root items did not end with a `/`

Comment: “I need help” [is not a question we can answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226254/135230).